# How to stop Firebase Database listen() method in Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I stop the `listen()` method in Python. The `listen()` method is listening continuously, but I want to stop listening for any changes in my database temporarily. I have tried the `close()` method to stop `listen()` method but, its not working for me. Thanks in advance :)

I'm calling the `listen()` method to check changes

```
db.reference('Users/Requests/user1').listen(listener)
```

By calling this `close()` method, it doesn't stop listening

```
db.reference('Users/Requests/user1').listen(listener).close()
```

If I'm wrong, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the returned object from the first call to `listen()`.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db) for `listen()`.

> Returns:  An object that can be used to stop the event listener.
> Return type:  ListenerRegistration

So, you should use the [ListnerRegistration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db#firebase_admin.db.ListenerRegistration) object that was directly returned on the first call to `listen()` (do not call `listen()` again).

```
registration = db.reference('Users/Requests/user1').listen(listener)

...

registration.close()
```

Comment: Doug Stevenson,  bro it's working fine but I need a small help from you that is, I want to stop listening when my data is '5' at my reference field. How do I do that? I'm unable to do that because, it gives me an error when I call close() in listener() function.